# Нержавіюча сталь, нержавна чи неіржавна?

Tags: переклад, терміни, словосполучення

Я (як і більшість інших) завжди вживала НЕРЖАВІЮЧА СТАЛЬ. Декілька днів тому почула по радіо, що краще позбуватися термінів, які виражені дієприкметником. Натомість, запропонували НЕРЖАВНА СТАЛЬ.

Пошук такого варіанту не видає зовсім. СУМ знає тільки НЕРЖАВІЮЧИЙ. 
А от [Вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&oldid=21712668) видає купу варіантів, серед яких НЕРЖАВНИЙ немає:

> **Неіржа́вна**<sup>1</sup> (також **нержавіюча**<sup>[2]</sup>, **нержавка́**<sup>3</sup>, **нержавійна**<sup>4</sup> або **неіржавійна**<sup>4</sup>) **сталь** (також *нержавійка*<sup>5</sup>, *інокс*<sup>6</sup>) — стійка до корозії у атмосфері та агресивних середовищах сталь з вмістом хрому не менше 11,5% та малим вмістом вуглецю (0,03…0,20%).
>
> <sub>Примітки:
>
>   1. ↑ [Термінологічний словник](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/new_books/Documents/terminologichnyj-visnyk-2013-1.pdf). Випуск 2(1). Інститут української мови. НАНУ. 2013
>
>   2. ↑ [нержавіючий](http://sum.in.ua/s/nerzhavijuchyj) // Словник української мови : в 11 т. — К. : Наукова думка, 1970—1980.
>
>   3. ↑ [нержавкий](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) // Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови (з дод. і допов.) / уклад. і гол. ред. В. Т. Бусел. — 5-те вид. — К. ; Ірпінь : Перун, 2005. — ISBN 966-569-013-2.
>
>   4. ↑ [Російсько-українські словники](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)
>
>   5. ↑ [нержавійка](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0) // Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови (з дод. і допов.) / уклад. і гол. ред. В. Т. Бусел. — 5-те вид. — К. ; Ірпінь : Перун, 2005. — ISBN 966-569-013-2.
>
>   6. ↑ від англ. Inox, фр. acier inoxydable</sub>

До речі, в перекладах я останнім часом використовую саме НЕІРЖАВНИЙ, як у Вікіпедії головне слово. Одного разу мене виправив коректор, але після цього я стала використовувати саме це слово. Надалі воно всіх завжди влаштовувало.

Як же краще?

Answer (score 5):

Вакуленко М. О. порушує проблему термінології, а саме і використання слів, про які питаєте, у статті [ДЕЯКІ СУЧАСНІ ПРОБЛЕМИ СТАНДАРТИЗАЦІЇ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ
ТЕРМІНОЛОГІЇ](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwj50OfNj9XaAhVJFiwKHTteAi8QFghHMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Firbis-nbuv.gov.ua%2Fcgi-bin%2Firbis_nbuv%2Fcgiirbis_64.exe%3FC21COM%3D2%26I21DBN%3DUJRN%26P21DBN%3DUJRN%26IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD%3D1%26Image_file_name%3DPDF%2Fpsptkl_2010_17_11.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0oiosmEwJJBa0iDwUA-RjS). Автор вважає, що:

> *Пропонована заміна* російської кальки нержавіюча (сталь) на нержавна, **нержавійна** (97.180) – це вживання наших новотворів, що є подані у російсько-українському словнику фізичної термінології. *Тільки тут описка:* ***не “нержавна”, а неіржавна.***

Отже, на думку науковця, це лише ***пропоновані новотвори*** (!). Саме тому у СУМі-11 та деяких інших словниках, зокрема й у [Великому тлумачному словнику сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005.](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/99569/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9) закріплено словосполучення "нержавіюча сталь".

Однак, аби уникнути аналогії з російською у слові "нержавіюча", справді можна замінювати його на *нержавійна*, адже це вже ближче до питомих слів.

Comment: Чому саме на *нержавійну*, чому не на *неіржавну*. *Неіржавна* мені більш-менш зрозуміла, це така, що не можа іржавіти, а як відбувся словотівр *нержавійної*?

Comment: Особисто мені це слово здається більш милозвучним. Аналогія до мелодійна.

Comment: За старим правописом (скрипниківка) подвоєння голосних завжди уникалося, і вставлявся звук "й". Тобто правильним варіантом буде  "неїржавна". Також потрібно розуміти, що обидва новотвори "неїржавна" і "неїржавійна" не є абсолютно тотожними. Друге слово вказує на процес "іржавіти" (не буде іржавіти), тоді як перше прямо походить від слова іржа (не буде іржі). При двох конкуруючих словах із однаковим змістом потрібно надавати перевагу простішому.

Comment: @ЮрійГладьо, «за старим правописом (скрипниківка) подвоєння голосних завжди уникалося, і вставлявся звук „й“. Тобто правильним варіантом буде „неїржавна“» — невпевнений. Ми ж кажемо _неіснуючий_ (а не _неїснуючий_) і _неістотний_ (а не _неїстотний_).

Answer (score 3):

Вислів "неіржавна сталь" зустрічаємо в [Термінологічному словнику](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/new_books/Documents/terminologichnyj-visnyk-2013-1.pdf):

> Наприклад, термін личкування у сфері виробництва гідротурбін має такі
> значення: “захисна оболонка з **неіржавної сталі**, яка запобігає
> спрацюванню вала гідротурбіни” (СГТ);

Так само це слово є в [Російсько-українському словику](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C), а також там є і "нержавіюча сталь".

[Словник Кримського і Єфремова](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=rusb&highlight=):

> нержаві́лий, неіржа́вілий, що не іржа́віє, що не ржаві́є.

Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009:

> Нержавеющий – неіржавкий, неіржавний, нержавійний, іржостійкий,
> нержавілий, неіржавілий, що не іржавіє, що не ржавіє:
>
> • нержавеющая
> сталь – нержавійна (неіржавка) сталь (криця).

Російсько-український словник з інженерних технологій 2013р. (Марія Ганіткевич, Богдан Кінаш):

> нержаве́ющий неіржавки́й, нержаві́йний, нержаві́ючий

В СУМі у [коментарях](http://sum.in.ua/s/nerzhavijuchyj/komentari) до слова "нержавіючий" пишуть:

> Слово «неіржавний» практично не вживається в українській мові. У
> Корпусі української мови є лише одна цитата:
>
> *Для кожного Колен поклав дві тарілки з білої порцеляни, помережаної
> золотавими прожилками, і прибор з неіржавної сталі з ажурними ручками,
> всередині яких, укладені між двома шарами плексигласу, зичили щастя
> опудала сонечок (Борис Віан, Вибрані твори, пер., Харків: Фоліо, 1998)*
>
> Натомість слово «нержавіючий» широко вживається в сучасній українській
> мові.
>
> В якості синонімів до слова «нержавіючий», автори іноді вживають
> прикметники: нержавний, нержавливий, нержавійний, нержавий.
>
> Як іменник іноді вживаються: нержавійка, нержавочка.

[Український інтерес](https://uain.press/language/v-yacheslav-vasylchenko-mova-bazhayuchi-vs-ohochi-929465) радить не вживати вислів "нержавіюча сталь", а:

> Тут у нас цілий кастинг намалювався: неіржАвна, нержавкА, нержавІйна,
> неіржавІйна. Можливі ще також нержавійка та інокс.
> <sub>В'ячеслав Васильченко (05.09.2021). Мова: Бажаючі vs охочі</sub>

Однак, врахуйте, що все-таки в СУМі є прикметник "нержавіючий", тому, гадаю, що вислів "нержавіюча сталь" все-таки можна вживати. Також варіантом може бути "[корозійностійка сталь](https://mehanik-ua.ru/pidruchnik-materialoznavstvo/699-neirzhavni-korozijnostijki-stali.html)".